# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

Here is the jsp page i am coding:
My requirement is to display a row from the sql database.

```
    <%@page import="edu.mindscripts.BookAction"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
    <%@page import="edu.mindscripts.BookPojo"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.List"%>
    <%@page import="org.hibernate.Query"%>
    <%@page import="org.hibernate.Session"%>
    <%@page import="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate"%>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%!Object o; %>
    <%
        //Object o = session.getAttribute("template");
        //HibernateTemplate template = (HibernateTemplate)o;
        Cookie c[]=request.getCookies();

        for(Cookie c1:c)
        {
           out.println(c1);
           out.println(c1.getValue());
           session.setAttribute("temp",c1.getValue());
                }

                out.println(session.getAttribute("temp"));

                Object o=session.getAttribute("temp");
                out.println(o);

                HibernateTemplate template=(HibernateTemplate)o;
                out.println(template);
        %>
```

The output for the cookies are fine, but it is throwing exception when I try to use the HibernateTemplate

Where am I doing wrong.
I have another set up where the coding is working absolutely fine.

below is the exception

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to 
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate
    at org.apache.jsp.bookdetails_jsp._jspService(bookdetails_jsp.java:96)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at 


  org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.
      service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.
   serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.
  service(JspServlet.java:260)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.
     service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that `session.getAttribute("temp")` is returning a string, not a HibernateTemplate.

Take a look at all the areas of your code that set the session attribute 'temp' and make sure you haven't set a string value when you meant to set a hibernate template.

Answer (score 0):

Man, that's the problem of use **Scriptlet** in your web page, it's hard to maintain and is too difficult to read. The problem is here `HibernateTemplate template=(HibernateTemplate)o;`. Your **o** object is a String and not a **HibernateTemplate**, you'll have to debug your Controller and see what you put into 'temp' variable. Maybe, consider use **JSTL** instead of **Scriptlet**. Have a good day.